# Regex to match non-numbers

Tags: regex

I have a file in the format, where each line has double numbers seperated by spaces, e.g.:

```
1 -0.5 0.567 0.123
```

What is the correct way to find files *not* in this format? I've tried:

```
[^0123456789\.\-\s]
```

But it did not work, any help?

Comment: Is it because you are only looking for one character, not many? `[^0123456789\.\-\s]+`

Comment: Are you using grep to find the files?

Comment: @paul could you also state what the correct format is because weeding out the decimal and spaces might cause valid statements to be excluded as well

Comment: @chad:it's not working, there are some lines with words which I want to find and they are missed, @tinifni: yes grep

Comment: @paul simmons: Please post your input and the desired output.

Comment: ok, let's make it this way, I wan't to find what is not a "number", not a ".", not a "-", not a "e" and not a "whitespace"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
> grep '[^0123456789\. \-]' *
```

But note that this method will not notify you of formatting errors. For example:

```
1 -1.0.4 .012
```

is not the same format as what you specified but will not be matched.

EDIT: It looks like you can use the `[:space:]` character class as well.

```
> grep '[^0123456789\.[:space:]\-]' *
```

EDIT: And following that same logic, you can use the `[:digit:]` character class.

```
> grep '[^[:digit:]\.[:space:]\-]' *
```

Comment: @paul simmons, I included an answer, that likely indicates why `\s` caused your regex to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ grep -LP '^[\s\d.\-]+$' file1 file2 file3 file4
```

which really means

```
$ grep --files-without-match --perl-regexp '^[\s\d.\-]+$' file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason, upon closer inspection that it didn't work with `\s` is because `\s` matches any whitespace characters.  Which is equivelant to `[ \t\r\n]` (though some flavors might include other non-printing characters).  And because `\n` (line break) is included in this, you will get matches on nearly every line.

The only files that probably matched 'correctly' likely had an invalid last line that didn't include a line break.